# Are both of these algorithms Selection sort algorithms?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I was playing around, trying to optimize a bubble sort algorithm. After that I tried to learn Selection sort algorithms. Is the optimized version of bubble sort that I wrote a Selection sort algorithm? Did I implement in the correct way the Selection sort algorithm? Is the professor wrong at around 7:45 in this video
https://youtube.com/watch?v=72pcR7C9vdo&feature=youtu.be?

```
def optimized_bubble_sort(L):
    n = len(L)-1
    ordered = False
    while ordered == False:
        ordered = True
        for i in range(n):
            if L[i] > L[i+1]:
                L[i], L[i+1] = L[i+1], L[i]
                ordered = False
                n -= 1
return L
def selectionSort(L):
    unsorted_index_start = 0
    while unsorted_index_start != len(L):
        for i in range(unsorted_index_start,len(L)-1):
            if L[i] > L[i+1]:
                L[i], L[i+1] = L[i+1],L[i]
        unsorted_index_start += 1
    return L
```

Comment: If you're only ever swapping adjacent elements, it's a bubble sort, not a selection sort. Selection sort minimizes the swaps by first finding out where an element should go, and then moving it once. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: @m69: I don't agree with your description. You don't take some element and move it to its final place; instead you search for the element that goes in the next position and move it there.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is indeed a more accurate description.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any Selection Sort here.

Selection Sort works as follows:

- Find the smallest element of the array and move it to the first position.
- Find the second smallest element of the array and move it to the second position.
- And so on.

Obviously, the subsequent searches can ignore the already sorted prefix of the array.

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know why the actual version of selectionSort doesn't work with [1,2,4,0] as parameter?

Comment: So is the professor wrong at 7:45? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72pcR7C9vdo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: `usortedIndex` starts at 0 and increments with each pass. Selection Sort has a sorted sub-array at the beginning of the array that isn't looked at, and grows by one element with each iteration. But the function given is actually Bubble Sort. Which has a sorted sub-array at the end of the array, not the beginning.